# Error invalid operands to binary & (have 'int **' and 'int *')

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to figure out the length of the three sides of the triangle, then sort them in order, and see if the triangle is formed. I must use struct, but this error appears. my compiler is Dev C++ and the limitation of this problem is three point of triangle should be Integer. and tag name of struct should 'Point'. I need your assisstance with this.

error of this code is "invalid operands to binary & (have 'int **' and 'int *')"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

int main()
{
    Point p1, p2, p3;    
    
    int temp;

    printf("please input first Point\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &p1.x &p1.y);

    printf("second Point\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &p2.x &p2.y);
    
    printf("Third Point\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &p3.x &p3.y); 

    int aX = p2.x - p1.x;    
    int aY = p2.y - p1.y;    

    int a = sqrt(pow(aX, 2) + pow(aY, 2));
    
    int bX = p3.x - p2.x;    
    int bY = p3.y - p2.y;   

    int b = sqrt(pow(bX, 2) + pow(bY, 2));
    
    int cX = p3.x - p1.x;   
    int cY = p3.y - p1.y;   

    int c = sqrt(pow(cX, 2) + pow(cY, 2));
    
    if (a >= b){
        temp = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    if (b >= c){
        temp = c;
        c = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (a >= b){
        temp = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    
    if(c< a + a){
        printf("ture");
    }
    else{printf("false");}

    return 0;
}
```

what is a problem?

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: title is error name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because the compiler thinks you're trying to use the binary `&` operator (bitwise AND) with the arguments `&p1.x` and `p1.y`, which doesn't make sense.

That, in turn, is because you're missing commas between certain function arguments; for example, this:

```
    scanf("%lf %lf", &p1.x &p1.y);
```

should be this:

```
    scanf("%d %d", &p1.x, &p1.y);
```

(Note that I've also corrected the format specifier — it's `%d`, not `%lf`, for an `int`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use of binary **&** operator (bitwise AND) with the arguments `&p1.x` and `p1.y` is also wrong. I recommend you to refer more about [**Input-output operations**](https://www.sitepoint.com/data-input-and-output-in-c-part-1/).

I fixed your code, only the code not the theory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 

typedef struct Triangles{
    int x;
    int y;
} ;

int main()
{
    struct Triangles p1;
    struct Triangles p2;
    struct Triangles p3;   

    int temp;

    printf("please input first Point\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &p1.x ,&p1.y);

    printf("second Point\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &p2.x ,&p2.y);

    printf("Third Point\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &p3.x ,&p3.y); 

    int aX = p2.x - p1.x;    
    int aY = p2.y - p1.y;    

    int a = sqrt(pow(aX, 2) + pow(aY, 2));

    int bX = p3.x - p2.x;    
    int bY = p3.y - p2.y;   

    int b = sqrt(pow(bX, 2) + pow(bY, 2));

    int cX = p3.x - p1.x;   
    int cY = p3.y - p1.y;   

    int c = sqrt(pow(cX, 2) + pow(cY, 2));

    if (a >= b){
        temp = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }
    if (b >= c){
        temp = c;
        c = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    if (a >= b){
        temp = b;
        b = a;
        a = temp;
    }

    if(c< a + a){
        printf("ture");
    }
    else{printf("false");}

    return 0;
}
```

Forgot to mention the format specifier `%lf`(used for double) is wrong it must be `%d` for **int*.*Cheers!